# Accessing proper array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

The following array `["2", "8", "134", "137", "140"]` is generated via user input.  The controller action invokes the arrays as follows:

```
params[:product_ids].each do |product_id|
  @product = Product.where('id = ?', product_id).first
end
```

Unfortunately when calling the values in the view (for development control purposes)

```
<% params[:product_ids].each do |t| %>
  <%= t %> <%= @product.id %><br />
<% end %>
```

is rendering the proper value for `t` but is then associating it with `140` five times.

```
2 140
8 140
134 140
137 140
140 140
```

thus accessing the LAST item of the array and ignoring the key.  When this is attempted in the controller:

```
params[:product_ids].each do |k, product_id|
```

it is returning  `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

How can the controller be defined to appropriately access the parameter's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assinging the values in a loop to the same variable, put it outside the loop, and use `#map` to get values as a Transaction model for all product ids, so:

```
@transactions = params[:product_ids].map do |product_id|
   [ Transaction.where(product_id: product_id).first ]
end
```

and then:

```
<%= @transactions %>
```

Comment: @Malo.  This syntax does generate data.  What surprised me is that `<%= @products %>` returned `["2", #<Product id: 2, struttura_id: 1,` [...] `["8", #<Product id: 8, struttura_id: 1, ` etc. In other words, the value, followed by the object's data.  Then if I want to loop through each and create new records `@products.each do |product| params[:transaction][:product_id] = product.id @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction]` I cannot as this is accessing an array...

Comment: @Jerome well, and what did you want to get? =)

Comment: @Malo  The Product's id...  But I believe my reasoning has fallen into a circular trap.  It would've been more direct to have gone with `params[:product_ids].each do |product_id| params[:transaction][:product_id] @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction]` ...

Comment: @Jerome what product's did you wish to get?

Comment: one transaction per param[:product_id]

Comment: @Jerome well Transaction is a model/record? If yes Have it product_id?

Comment: @Mala.  That was useful, thank you.  It did lead to an subsequent issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588542/rails-controller-behaviour-processing-inconsistency

Answer (score 2):

In this piece of code:

```
params[:product_ids].each do |product_id|
  @product = Product.where('id = ?', product_id).first
end
```

You're updating `@product` instance variable n times (where n is size of `params[:product_ids]` table). At the end, `@product` instance variable holds `Product` with id which is last element of `params[:product_ids]`, in your case it's `140`. I guess it would be better if you set products array, like this:

```
@products = Product.where(id: params[:product_ids])
```

so you could iterate over them:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this syntax `Product.where(id: params[:product_ids])` correct?  I haven't come across it before?

Comment: @Jerome it's correct. It generates SQL with `IN` clause.

Comment: this is generating `Product Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" IS NULL` and only once...  (postgresql is db)

Comment: @Jerome So your `params[:product_ids]` is probably `nil`.

Comment: Not really. `<%= params[:product_ids] %>` returns ` ["2", "8", "134", "137", "140"] `

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
params[:product_ids].each do |product_id|
  @product = Product.where('id = ?', product_id).first
end 
# you set @product = 2
# @product = 8
# ...
# @product = 140  last value of @product is 140
```

solution

```
@products = params[:product_ids].map do |p_id|
   {p_id => Product.find_by(id: p_id)}    
end
```

In your view

```
<% @products.each do |k, v| %>
  <%= k %> <%= v %><br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: `Product.find_by(p_id)` won't work. It should be either `Product.find_by(id: p_id)` or `Product.find_by_id(p_id)`.

Comment: nope, `find_by` without column name doesn't behave like `find_by(id: p_id)`, at least in 4.1.6.

Comment: You are right, I was not looking carefully, it returns first object from DB

Comment: ... or simply raises an error, if you use postgresql for example.